# Laravel - View:Make not working properly when including external files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am getting one very strange error using laravel

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

It loads the index.php inside view properly

but

When I have something like `http://localhost:8000/xyz` (does not exist) then also it route to the index.php and all js file gets loaded properly but when i goto `http://localhost:8000/xyz/abc` (does not exist)

It doesn't load js files properly and my page renders with error

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return View::make('index');
});
```

My app missing function.

Why is it happening.

More to this I have another laravel instance and that doesn't give such problem it can also deal with

`http://localhost:8000/xyz/abc/ahbfd/dfdfd/dfdfd`

(does not exist)

without any error.

Hope i am pretty clear.

Comment: Did you try with `App::error` in `/start/global.php` ?

Comment: app error is already there

`App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
 Log::error($exception);
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linking to JS or CSS files works best with `URL::asset()` or `ÙRL::to()`. Assuming your package lies in the **vendors** folder, you would do something like this:

```
<script src="{{URL::to('/vendor')}}/packages/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or for the **public/assets** folder

```
<script src="{{URL::asset('/')}}/packages/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

This way, you assure that Laravel creates a correct path to your files corresponding to the called route.

Comment: no luck still the same. It is routing properly that is not the issue but the js files referenced inside the view is not getting loaded properly.

Comment: Can you post, how you link to the js files?

Comment: `<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="packages/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="welcome">
  <h1>You have arrived.</h1>
 </div>
</body>`

Comment: It is getting loaded when i am accessing `http://localhost:8000/xyz` why not in `http://localhost:8000/xyz/abc`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the answer i found from R&D.

you need to add
`<base href="/" target="_top">
</base>`
before `<html>` may be or wherever you find it suitable.

Comment: but i guess probably the `<base>` is the easiest i can do because i have so many JS included in my `index.php` so its bit difficult and time consuming task to replace the script syntax and also will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: No because with `Url::to()` laravel takes care of it ;-)